# SPSS Create new numeric output variable conditional on specific word in string

Tags: string, variables, numbers, spss

In my data set I have a column named `Info` that contains sentences that involve 2 conditions: one with information about a painter and another one one with random facts. The condition that talks about a painter always contains the word "painter", while the other condition doesn't.

I would like to achieve the following:
Create a new variable so that if the word "painter" appears in my string the new variable should give me output 1. Otherwise, when the word "painter" is not identified, the new variable should give me output 0.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
compute Painter=char.index(Info,"painter")>0.
exe.
```

The new variable `Painter` will have 1 when the word was mentioned in `info` and 0 when it wasn't.